# Define a shortcut that works in all forms of a win form application

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, showdialog

I'm working on a `MDI` winforms project, I want to user uses <kbd>F3</kbd> shortcut to open a search form in every where in application, so I used following code in my `MDI` parent form and set the parent form's `KeyPreview` to `true`:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
   if (keyData == (Keys.F3)) {
      //Show search form
      return true;
   }
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

The shortcut works in `MDI` parent and child forms, but If I open a form from one of `MDI` child forms using `.ShowDialog()` the shortcut doesn't work in last form, in the other word, the shortcut, works in `childForm`:

```
//in the parent form
var childForm = new Form1();
childForm.MdiParent = parentForm;
childForm.KeyPreview = true;
childForm.Show();
```

but doesn't work in `grandChildForm` form:

```
//in the child form
var grandChildForm = new Form2();
grandChildForm.KeyPreview = true;
grandChildForm.ShowDialog();
```

How can I solve the problem, without repeating `ProcessCmdKey()` method in all forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `baseForm`:

```
public partial class baseForm : Form
{
    public baseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.F3))
        {
            //Show search form
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

And let all your others forms inherit from it:

```
public partial class Form1 : baseForm
```

Then any common functionality you want can be added to baseForm.